# This integral is divergent - but why?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

The following integral is divergent:

$$\int _1^{\infty }\:\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{x+1}\:\sin\left(2x\right)dx$$

I am struggling to understand why, because it passes Dirichlet test as $\sin(2x)$ is bounded and  $\frac{\ln\left(x\right)}{x+1}$ is positive in the range, and monotonous down to zero.

I guess I have here some wrong assumptions - I'd like to understand what they are.

Thanks,

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{x+1} \, dx$ is divergent, and $\ln(x)$ doesn't make it better.

Comment: You didn't quote the Dirichlet test correctly, but it passes it. So why on earth do you think it's divergent?! @md2perpe the $\sin(2x)$ makes it better.

Comment: @ProfessorVector That is the answer in my textbook

Comment: I guess it is a mistake of the textbook, should I delete this question?

Comment: No, tell people what textbook they shouldn't trust, instead.

Comment: It's not Lebesgue integrable, but as a limit $\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_1^R$ it is convergent since it behaves like an alternating series.

Comment: What is your textbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dirichlet's test claims that for two *continuous* functions $f,g\in[a,\infty]$ where $f,g\geq 0$, if a certain $M$ exists such that $\left|\int_a^bf(x)dx\right|\leq M$ for every $a\leq b$, and $g(x)$ is monotonically decreasing, and $\lim_{X\to\infty}g(x)=0$, then $\int_a^\infty fg$ is convergent.

So let's check this here, with $f(x)=\sin 2x$ and $g(x)=\frac{\log x}{1+x}$. The function $g(x)$ decreases as soon as $x\geq e$, and we have $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$. Moreover, for all $b\geq 1$ 
$$\left|\int_ 1^b\sin 2x\,dx\right|=\frac{1}{2}|\cos 2-\cos 2b|\leq 1$$
It follows from Dirichlet's test that the integral $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\log x}{1+x}\sin 2x\,dx$ converges.

So it seems your textbook has it wrong.